# Where can I test existence of an ENV value in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails app I would like to test the existence of a particular ENV key- value pair ie `not ENV['my_key'].nil?` and raise an exception (and make it fail to compile) when I do `rails server` or deploy to Heroku.

Where is the best part in Rails structure to put this test?

Comment: Ruby does not compile. You can raise an exception when the applciation boots, for rails the best place would be an initalizer, Simply put your check in a new file in `config/initializers` folder.

Comment: Thanks @BroiSatse. Please can you put this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your planning to make a file for Environment Variable like (key, value), you can simply add

**YML** file inside config directory of your app.

For example:

```
local_env.yml
```

Data is like:

```
SAMPLE_DEVELOPMENT: 'localhost:3000'
```

Then you can get it, by (e.g. in controller):

```
ENV["SAMPLE_DEVELOPMENT"]
```